# Does this function necessitate a class method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

class Website:
    def __init__(self, username, privateID):
        self.username = username
        self.privateID = privateID

    # URL's to query
    AccountBalance = 'https://website.com/private/AccountBalance?{0}?nonce={1}' # 0 requires private ID num

    TopComments = 'https://website.com/public/TopComments?nonce={0}'


    def get_AccountBalance(self):
        nonce = gen_nonce(8)
        print(json.load(urlopen(AccountBalance.format(self.privateID, nonce))))

    @staticmethod
    def gen_nonce(length):
        return ''.join([str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in range(length)])
```

I'm still trying to understand when to use the different types of class methods and I'm stuck on this project I'm working on. There will be more than one instance of my class but the URL to be queried will always remain the same for all of them, so I will make the URL's a class variable. However, when actually retrieving the information from the URL will I have to use a class method, static method, or abstract? I assume that for the account balance I would use abstract since the private ID's would change from instance to instance. The `gen_nonce()` would be static since it does not require the use of any class or instance variables. However, for retrieving the top comments would I use a class method because it uses the class variable url, or an abstract method because not every instance will be calling it at the same time?

Comment: Note: making it a `staticmethod` isn't required. FWIW: I essentially never use `@staticmethod`. Now, your `get_AccountBalance` does not *necessitate* a `@classmethod`, but you do need to use `self.AccountBalance` to access the class attribute. Or `Website.AccountBalance` explicitly. You *could* use a classmethod if you'd prefer. But it's pretty much never *necessary*.

Comment: Your `Website` class always has a user name and a private ID as data. If `TopComments` doesn't require the data, why is it part of the class? I think you really want two classes, one to model the web site and one to model a *user* of the web site.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. First, abstract methods are only found in abstract base classes. If you intend to instantiate a class, you can ignore them.

Most methods will be instance methods; that's why you don't need to decorate them.

A class method is effectively an alternative constructor. If you feel the need for multiple `__init__` methods, then the most basic one is `__init__` and the rest are defined as class methods, usually implemented with `__init__`.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @classmethod
    def from_bar(cls, b):
        return cls(b.x)

f1 = Foo(3)
b = Bar()
f2 = Foo.from_bar(b)  # Create a Foo from a Bar without having to know how that actually happens
```

A static method isn't really a method at all. It's just a regular function that you stick in a class to avoid polluting the global namespace.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use the `cls` parameter?

Comment: I had `self` at one point, but I thought I fixed that well before your comment?

Comment: No, I mean your `from_bar` classmethod doesn't use `cls` so it could just be a plain function. If you are going to make it a classmethod might as well use `return cls(b.x)`